# Scrapy recursive crawling with max DEPTH - Infinite loop

Tags: recursion, scrapy, depth

i'm new with scrapy, i'm trying to build a spider that must do this kind work:

Extract all links from a generic web page recursively and with a specific depth.

I'm tryng to do this with following code:

```
class MySpider(CrawlSpider):
    settings.overrides['DEPTH_LIMIT'] = 1
    name = "cnet"
    allowed_domains = ["cnet.com"]
    start_urls = ["http://www.cnet.com/"]

    rules = (Rule (SgmlLinkExtractor(allow_domains=('cnet.com',)), callback="parse_items", follow= True),)

    def parse_items(self, response):
        print ""
        print "PARSE ITEMS"
        print ""

        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        titles = hxs.select('//a')
        items = []
        for titles in titles:
            item = NewsItem()
            item ["title"] = titles.select("text()").extract()
            item ["link"] = titles.select("@href").extract()

            if(len(item["link"]) > 0) and (self.allowed_domains[0] in item["link"][0]):
                print ""
                print response.meta['depth']
                print item ["title"]
                print item ["link"]
                print ""

            items.append(item)
        return(items)
```

**But it seems to go on an INFINITE loop, Any suggestion?**

Thanks a lot!

Comment: can you be more specific about going infinite loop ? On the same url you mean ? On the domain ?

Comment: on the same domain :(